# Excelfunction for getting sheetname to appear in a cell

Tags: excel

I have 10 worksheets in a Excelfile and in the last sheet I want to get each sheetname in a cell.

Lets say sheet 1 is called "Black". I want this sheetname to appear in sheet 10 in a cell etc.

How can I get the sheetname into a cell with a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do exactly what you're asking using either a macro or a custom function.  I'll give you the custom function:

## Function:

```
Public Function sheetName(sheetIndex As Integer) As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Application.Volatile True

    Set wb = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Parent

    If sheetIndex < 1 Or sheetIndex < wb.Sheets.Count Then
        sheetName = wb.Sheets(sheetIndex).Name
    Else
        sheetName = "Index Out of Range!"
    End If
End Function
```

## Use:

Paste the above code into a module in your workbook(if you need help with this just ask).  Then use the formula: `=sheetName(TheNumberOfTheSheet)`  where `TheNumberOfTheSheet` is 1 for the first sheet, 2 for the second, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Once the workbook has been saved:

```
=CELL("filename")
```

will return the full path to the sheet. If you want just the tab name it requires some string manipulation also, such as:

```
=MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("]",CELL("filename"))+1,LEN(CELL("filename")))
```

A Swedish version might be:

```
=EXTEX(CELL("filnamn");HITTA("]";CELL("filnamn"))+1;LÄNGD(CELL("filnamn")))
```

Comment: Thanks @pnuts i just want the tab name.

Comment: @user2986959 please use the formula in saved workbook

Comment: It says that the formula isnt valid. The workbook is saved. I use Swedish Excel. Is it ok to use exactly same formula for swe version? @pnuts

Comment: Actually i tested in google docs excel which is english and i still got error like: Error: Wrong number of arguments to CELL. Expected 2 arguments, but got 1 arguments.

Comment: This one works in swedish Excel: =EXTEX(CELL("filnamn");HITTA("]";CELL("filnamn"))+1;LÄNGD(CELL("filnamn"))) but how can i get all tabs. This givs me the tab im curently using but how to get the others tab1 tab2 etc? @pnuts

Comment: Seems like every tab i paste this formla into gets the last tab name. Cant be used for many tabs?!